# I can't access the database with this set of code. Using both PDO and another method, and they dont acess the config.php

Tags: php, mysql

```
<body>
    <h1> helloo </h1>
    <div class="gallery">
    <?php 
    // Include database configuration file 
    require 'dbConfig.php'; 

    // Retrieve images from the database 
    $query = $DB->query("SELECT * FROM /phpgallery/images WHERE status = 1 ORDER BY uploaded_date DESC"); 

    if($query->num_rows > 0){ 
        while($row = $query->fetch_assoc()){ 
            $imageThumbURL = 'images/'.$row["file_name"]; 
            $imageURL = 'images/'.$row["file_name"]; 
    ?>
        <a href="<?php echo $imageURL; ?>" data-fancybox="gallery" data-caption="<?php echo $row["title"]; ?>" >
            <img src="<?php echo $imageThumbURL; ?>" alt="" />
        </a>
    <?php } 
    } ?>
</div>
</body>
```

```
<body>
    <h1> helloo </h1>
    <div class="gallery">
    <?php 
    // Include database configuration file 
    require 'dbConfig.php'; 

    // Retrieve images from the database 
    $query = $DB->query("SELECT * FROM /phpgallery/images WHERE status = 1 ORDER BY uploaded_date DESC"); 

    if($query->num_rows > 0){ 
        while($row = $query->fetch_assoc()){ 
            $imageThumbURL = 'images/'.$row["file_name"]; 
            $imageURL = 'images/'.$row["file_name"]; 
    ?>
        <a href="<?php echo $imageURL; ?>" data-fancybox="gallery" data-caption="<?php echo $row["title"]; ?>" >
            <img src="<?php echo $imageThumbURL; ?>" alt="" />
        </a>
    <?php } 
    } ?>
</div>
</body>
```

These two files are in the same folder, but the database is in another folder.

E:\Xampp\htdocs\phpgallery\images  <- Images where database is stored.
E:\Xampp\htdocs\dynamicImageGallery <- Where I am running the code from.

Comment: /phpgallery/images Are you sure that that is your tablename in your database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using MySQL, you seem to be calling a directory where you should be calling a table name. For instance, if you are storing the images in a table called tbl_images you'll need to use a query with the table name not the directory of the database or image store.

tbl_images

```
| id | file_name   |
|----|-------------|
| 1  | image01.jpg |
```

index.php

```
$query = $DB->query("SELECT * FROM tbl_images WHERE status = 1 ORDER BY uploaded_date DESC");
```

Hope this solves your problem.

Comment: Thanks! Dreamweaver completely messed with my config file, and I didn't manage to paste it here. I have had to edit with notepad to get it correct. I will be deleting this post. I will bear in mind the advice you gave me.

Comment: I know the feeling, have you tried Visual Studio Code for PHP. I find Dreamweaver only good for design.